# CSS Issue on Safari

Tags: css, browser, safari, cross-browser, css-animations

I've got a box with a nice hover overlay that animates in. This works fine on all browsers, however on Safari (desktop and mobile) there are some styles that aren't applied correctly (Width, height, and padding). When I toggle these styles off and on again using the inspector everything is as it should be, Safari just doesn't seem to correctly apply at the beginning. Also, there is no CSS inheritance issue as Safari claims to be using the rules as defined below, adding `!important` has no effect. See code and images below.

**HTML**

---

```
<div class="col-md-5 hla-building-col animated fadeInUp" style="height:350px;background-image:url(/placeholder.jpg)">
   <div class="overlay text-center">
      <h3>Karma</h3>
      <p>Sitting right in the heart of it all...</p>
      <a>Learn More</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

---

```
.hla-building-col {
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 50px -6px rgba(102,103,102,1);
}    
.hla-building-col .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(165px);
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
.hla-building-col:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px 15px;
  /**** EDIT: Properties above are not rendering ****/
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(0);
  /*     transition: all 600ms ease; */
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
.hla-building-col .overlay p, .hla-building-col .overlay a {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hla-building-col:hover .overlay p, .hla-building-col:hover .overlay a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
    transition-delay: 1000ms;
}


@keyframes slidein {
  from {
        width: 60%;
    height: 40px;
    transform: translateY(165px);
    padding-top: 8px;
  }

  to {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(0);
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

[image: Sample of intended and broken styles]

Answer (score 1):

Safari uses WebKit, you can add it to your css with the `-webkit`- prefix.

Read more about it here: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) and here: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions)

Comment: There are also some useful tools online for handling cross-browser prefixes. Googling just for "auto prefixer", this was the second result: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: I am aware of vendor prefixes, unfortunately I have no issues in Chrome so it is likely not a WebKit problem. Also the properties at issue are width, height, and padding.